# Circle within given Tangent and Diameter Chord

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

In figure

[image]

- There is a Circle with center point C and radius 4
- Points A & B lie on the circle
- AB = 6
- DE is Perpendicular Bisector of AB
- C lies on DE
- DE = 43.5

How to create a circle with radius 3 whose center should lie on DE, and should have same tangents as the first circle?

Comment: Do you know the distance $CE$ and need to find new centre??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the information that radius is $3$. So you *just need the position of centre*. Let the centre of new circle be $O$.

Then we can find distance OE using similarity of triangles (not shown in figure, right triangles formed using tangents and radiuses)

$$\frac{OE}{3} = \frac{CE}{4} \tag{1}$$

Since $AD=3$ is known and also the radius $AC=4$, we therefore know $DC = \sqrt{AC^2-AD^2} = \sqrt{7}$.

Also we know $CE = DE-DC = 43.5-\sqrt{7}$. Thus we know the distance of new centre $O$ from $E$ as

$$OE=\frac{3}{4}(43.5-\sqrt{7})$$